# Excel power query taking extremely long loading to data model

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have one table in Excel 365 that I transform using a few queries to output as 2 pivot tables and 1 table. One of these queries is also loaded to the data model as I need to create measures.

The operation is taking extremely and erratically long - approximately 25 to 70 minutes just to load a query involving 14 columns and 100 rows. The same operation in Power BI consistently takes 2.5 minutes in comparison. After spending 2 weeks on diagnostics, I eventually isolate the problem to

1. Output query to pivot table and Load to data model.
2. Row-wise operations in query (if loaded to data model).

I had spent 2 week refactoring my code. This includes buffering what can be buffer and optimising every operation as best as I can. Also tried "Fast Data Load" but doesn't help.

Not loading the query to data model means everything only takes 2-3 minutes. But I cannot not load the query to the data model because I need measures.

Is there anything else I can do to fix this extremely long load to data model operation?

Comment: Did you turn off "background refresh"?

Comment: Yes, I have done that.

Comment: The `*.Buffer()` family of functions can increase, or decrease performance (depending on the environment) -- make sure you have `Table.Key()`s set, they can have a big impact on performance: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2018/03/16/improving-the-performance-of-aggregation-after-a-merge-in-power-bi-and-excel-power-query-gettransform/

Comment: Can't really try Table.AddKey as the columns are dynamic. Not sure how many there would be or what type.

Also, the more "Refresh Data" I do, the longer it takes. Longest was 5+ hours to refresh what initially only took 20 mins. With or without Table.Buffer. And this is for sample data with 15 columns and 50 rows. It's clearly something to do with Excel's Power Pivot.